# Incorrect comparison of datetime and datetime2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, datetime, datetime2

I know that it is not a good practice to have an implicit type convert. But this is really unexpected behavior when a lower value can suddenly become higher.

```
declare @LastSelectedDate DATETIME = '2021-11-09 13:52:29.187'
declare @LastSelectedDate_1 DATETIME2(7) = '2021-11-09 13:52:29.1866667'


SELECT IIF(@LastSelectedDate_1 > CAST(@LastSelectedDate AS DATETIME2), 1, 0)
SELECT IIF(@LastSelectedDate_1 > @LastSelectedDate, 1, 0)
```

Is this a bug or I am missing something? I am using sql server 2016.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yeah, I have no idea why they thought this behaviour would be a good idea.

It is "by design" [rather than a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15) though

> An example of a breaking change protected by compatibility level is an
> implicit conversion from datetime to datetime2 data types. Under
> Database Compatibility Level 130, these show improved accuracy by
> accounting for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different
> converted values. To restore previous conversion behavior, set the
> Database Compatibility Level to 120 or lower.

Specifically `datetime` that end `3` are treated as though it was `3` recurring and `datetime` ending `7` are treated as though it was `6` recurring. `datetime` that end `0` are unaffected. (these were the only possibilities for that datatype as it has 300 "ticks" per second)

Restricting compatibility level to solve this single issue seems a sledge hammer solution. You can explicitly cast it to `datetime2(3)` to avoid this

```
DECLARE @LastSelectedDate DATETIME = '2021-11-09 13:52:29.187'

SELECT CAST(@LastSelectedDate AS DATETIME2(7)), 
       CAST(CAST(@LastSelectedDate AS DATETIME2(3)) AS DATETIME2(7))
```

Returns

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-11-09 13:52:29.1866667 | 2021-11-09 13:52:29.1870000 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```